# STM32L051K8U won't run without 3V when it should run at 1.65V

Tags: stm32

I've just switched the MCU of my board from a STM32L021K4T to STM32L051K8U and have a problem I can't figure out.

My circuit is powered by a CR2032 into a 2V LDO regulator and the original MCU (STM32L021K4T) ran perfectly with no problems. But the new MCU (STM32L051K8U) won't run without 3V, even though it say it runs down to 1.65V.

I've tried going through the datasheet to see if there some thing I need to set, but I'm at a loss.

The brown out reset option bit is set at 0 "BOR Level OFF, reset level threshold the 1.45V,-1.55V"

The voltage from the regulator is a steady 2V +/- 1mV.

To the best of my ability to tell, it never starts executing code. With the CR2032 in and the voltage being regulated to 2V, I can't connect to the chip with my debugger (I think it's because the debugger needs to see the chips voltage at ~3V). Sorry, if I didn't answer your question. I'm still pretty new to these. I appreciate the help though!

But, with the previous chip, what I'd do was program it with the 3V from my programmer. After it's programmed, I could disconnect and put int the CR2032 and it starts running.

With the new chip, I can program it the same way. But when I disconnect the programmer and put int the battery, nothing happens. I've bypassed the regulator and supplied the chip directly with the CR2032 and it works. Just not with the 2V from the regulator, when the previous chip worked (exact same board layout and parts).

So, it seems like to me that there is some option bit or clock configuration or something like that, that I have misconfigured. But I can't find anything wrong and anything seems related, when changed doesn't fix the problem.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you can start up at 1.65 or have to start up at a higher voltage and then it can operate down to 1.65?

Comment: If I'm reading the datasheet right it appears that it can start up at 1.65V (or 1.8V with BOR enabled), which is lower than my voltage of 2V

Comment: worth a shot, you beat me to it I was about to look at it.  what about the current?  I had one of these stm32s that I was trying to power minimally and there was a spike on power up, but once you got over that then you could run it on like 10 microamps, so I had to get over that hump.  I was not able to power up with the setup I had I had but once powered it would run for a long time on a charged cap or battery.  so thats what made me think of this.  YMMV...

Comment: some debuggers, most, should have a sense line that you connect to vcc used by the part so that it can sample the midpoint of the signal back from the chip under test...

Comment: re-reading your question, do the electrical specs from the older part match or are they similar?  if you are starting up higher and cleanly dropping it onto the battery which is 2V, I would also expect it to work.  hate to say it but is there a reason why you cant stick with the old mcu?

Comment: I don't know about startup current but the chip would only be using about~500uA while running, so I don't expect it to overwhelm the battery with a current requirement.

Comment: The electrical specs are similar if not exact (But I'm guessing I'm stupidly missing _something_). And two reasons I moved to this chip is: I needed an even smaller package so I was looking for a QFN (4x4mm!) and the most important is this is the closest-matching chip the assembler had.